# Avoiding crawl time for noindex pages

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, nofollow, noindex

I have pages with `noindex` in robots meta tag (specifically inner site search results pages). Because my site has many pages and Google hasn't crawled them all and I'm trying to help his crawler focus and not waste time on irrelevant pages (such as these `noindex` pages).

If I add a `nofollow` to the **a href that links to these pages**, will that help?
Is the `noindex` in the target pages helpful to avoid crawl time 'waste'?
Should I make those pages in a specific folder and block through *robots.txt*?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid loss of time for web-crawlers, you can put `nofollow` in robots meta tag for webpages which already have `noindex` but putting a `rel="nofollow"` in `<a>` tags in webpages links which link webpages with `noindex` in robots meta tag seems irrelevant to me.

`rel="nofollow"` tells to search engines that you can't trust on these links. There is no reason why you can't trust on webpages of your website.

Comment: I didn't explain correctly. I meant adding a nofollow to the <a href> not the page itself...

Comment: I have edited my answer to explain you why a `rel="nofollow"` is not a good idea either.

Comment: @Noam: But, as Zistoloen implies, if you don't have a `nofollow` in the robots meta tag for the page then the bot will need to crawl the `noindex` page in order to extract the links. In order to prevent the page from being crawled then block with robots.txt.